# Exporting to .csv format from matlab or log file

Tags: matlab, csv, export

I am running a simulation which displays a list of parameters at every time step and displays it on the command window. It also generates a  separate log file which shows all the parameters at each time step.Is there a way where i can export into a .csv file in a structured manner.There is no structure in which the output is displayed.Every row has different number of parameters.
Part of output looks like this

```
 Time = 80.0000 sec =======================================
rmc_gr   22  DTT_pos_in:    5  Veh_Spd(mph):    1.9  fhtyi_st_pr_des:    3    ttgyda_pc_dd:   0.000            
 rmip_pc_dot_dd:  -0.000 rmssh__thld:   0.000 rmssh_tm_tin_exit:   0.000 rmssh_gr_des:    1   
 tin_ne:   676  tdc_t_bar:   602  tdc_nbar:   407  tdc_n_isb_bar:     0  
 tfp_nerq:  7000  tcrpmbar:   408    tpm__bar:    89 


r56sc_gr_t:   22  sacr_d_ele:    0  saprc_p_lnp: 180        
 saseq_gr:   22  sautl_gr_end:    0  sautl_gr_strt:    0  sautl_gr_end:   22    
 sautl_grstrt:    0  sa_slp:    0  satq_tqhld: 0.000000  sacorst:    0
```

Comment: can you be more specific? what is the structure of Time and r56sc_gr_t?

Comment: You can read your text file with `scanf()` and then export the result in .csv with `csvwrite()`